# form_tag not routing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am trying to get a form tag working in rails 3 but I keep getting a Routing Error:

No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"posts"}.

Here is the code for the for_tag:

```
 <%= form_tag search_post_path, method: :get do %>
    <br />
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Search</legend>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      <%= link_to_function "Clear", "$('search_field').clear()" %>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
  <% end %>
```

I have a method in my posts_controller that is called search.  This is what  put in my routes.rb file:

```
 post 'search' => 'posts#search'

  resources :posts do
    member do
      post 'search'
      get 'search'
    end
  end
```

I feel like I have tried everything in my routes file and nothing worked.  At one point I got the for_for to show up but then when I hit the submit button, I got a NoMethodError for the method 'search'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You route "search" is on a member, so the matching URL is /posts/:id/search.
However you do not provide an ID, hence the error.
You should put the search route inside a collection block, like so :

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

So the matching URL will be /posts/search.

Comment: I tried that but I get a NoMethodError:  undefined method `search'

Comment: Oh yeah, it should be search_posts_path, not search_post_path.